# Escape from guest CentOS by Ctrl+Alt+Del in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, centos

I use CentOS 7 as a guest OS in VirtualBox (host is Windows 10). When the mouse cursor is in the guest OS, the only way to get out of it seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Sometime double cliking <kbd>Right Control</kbd> key works, but sometimes it doesn't. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> takes me out of the guest OS, but also locks the host OS Windows 10. How can I send escape signal only to the guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

The way to release mouse and keyboard from the guest is to press the [**Host key**](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal) which is the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key by default. VirtualBox always explains this to you the first time you run a VM and you need to read that

If the <kbd>Host</kbd> key doesn't work reliably then chances are it has been partly broken, in which case you can go to settings to change the <kbd>Host</kbd> key to another key, or replace the keyboard. Another theory is that some applications hooked the keyboard and steal the keys so VirtualBox sometimes just doesn't receive the key events

Comment: The host key is Right Ctrl now, but it is not working. It sometimes works, but sometimes does not. I cannot figure out in what circumstances it works.

Comment: @user67275 are you in fullscreen mode? then try `Host+F`. If you want to send Ctrl+Alt+Del to only the guest then use `Host+Del`. Another possibility is that the keys are captured by some other apps before Virtualbox receives them